The Stacks Editor should open in Markdown with preview mode by default
I started a new question on Stack Overflow and the wizard form was shown for me, which uses the Stacks Editor.
The Stacks Editor showed edit text boxes, but did not show a view of the actual formatted text below (as the normal editing form does in the rest of Stack Exchange). Without it showing a preview, it makes it much harder to understand how the HTML question will look like once posted.
I’ve asked  a question Issues with the “Question Wizard”
And Makyen advised

(from memory) there's a mode switch toggle in the top-right corner
of the editor frame which should show 3 options. One of those options
is Markdown with preview. IIRC, it's the option on the right.

It will be good to have an option Markdown with preview by default as the most convenient and familiar from other SE editors mode.
